# Golang Defer with point

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type userinfo struct {
    id int
}

func main() {
    user := new(userinfo)
    user = nil
    fmt.Println("nil user address : ", &user)
    defer Println(user)
    if user == nil {
        user = &userinfo{
            id: 1,
        }
        fmt.Println("nil user point new user:", &user)
    }
}

func Println(user *userinfo) {
    fmt.Println("defer: ", &user)
    fmt.Println("defer:", user)
}
```

The result is:

```
    nil user address :  0xc00000e028
    nil user point new user: 0xc00000e028
    defer:  0xc00000e038
    defer: <nil>
```

why the result print like this? I don't know how to understand the program

golang defer with point

Comment: Read https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements. The argument `user` to `defer Println(user)` is evaluated (read "fixed") the moment the line `defer Println(user)` is executed. At this moment user us nil. The line `fmt.Println("defer: ", &user)` is basically nonsensical, it prints the totally uninteresting address of the user parameter of Println.

Comment: Is your question about the printed pointer values or about the order of the printed lines? Defer only affects the order.

Answer (score 1):

1. `nil user address :  0xc00000e028` - Just an address of pointer
2. `nil user point new user: 0xc00000e028` - The same as previous
3. `defer Println(user)` parameters are evaluated immediately, but function is not called until return from surrounding function. In your case `user` points to `<nil>`. `user` pointer is passed by value to `Println` function and this is the reason why it's address is different: `0xc00000e038` (not `0xc00000e028`)

Maybe this code will help you (I made some messages a little bit more detailed):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type userinfo struct {
    id int
}

func main() {
    user := new(userinfo)
    fmt.Printf("1. Initilized user pointer address: %p, data address: %p (%v)\n", &user, user, user)

    user = nil
    fmt.Printf("2. Nil user pointer address: %p, data address: %p (%v)\n", &user, user, user)
    defer Println(user)

    if user == nil {
        user = &userinfo{
            id: 1,
        }
        fmt.Printf("3. Nil user point new user address: %p, data address: %p (%v)\n", &user, user, user)
    }
}

func Println(user *userinfo) {
    fmt.Printf("4. Defer user pointer address: %p, data address: %p (%v)\n", &user, user, user)
}
```

Output is quite similar:

```
1. Initilized user pointer address: 0xc000042020, data address: 0xc000012028 (&{0})
2. Nil user pointer address: 0xc000042020, data address: 0x0 (<nil>)
3. Nil user point new user address: 0xc000042020, data address: 0xc000012048 (&{1})
4. Defer user pointer address: 0xc000042030, data address: 0x0 (<nil>)
```

Comment: Yeah , your answer is so good , thanks!